# 2002 Chevy Tahoe rear brake issue

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, tahoe

We replaced all brake pads, rotors and calipers back in January 2017.  Yesterday, there was loss of braking - I couldn't slow down or stop so I used the engine to slow down and pull over - heat, noise and no braking ability seems to be on the rear driver's side brake.  Any experience with this type of issue?  Solution?  Have heard proportioning valve could need adjustment.